# How to use @Parameter in Micronaut?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, micronaut

I'm trying to inject a dependency with micronaut's DI container and would like to use a constructor with arguments/parameters for a bean. I read about the annotation @Parameter, but do not understand how to use it.

In the API reference it says:

> **public @interface Parameter**
>   Specifies that an argument to a bean constructor is user provided and a ParametrizedBeanFactory should be generated.
>   Should be applied only to constructor arguments and Bean factory methods

https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/api/io/micronaut/context/annotation/Parameter.html

Where should I put the annotation? Can I pass a variables value to a bean constructor?

Comment: Added new more specific question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54378321/5877195

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I solve circular dependency with android context in injected bean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54378321/how-can-i-solve-circular-dependency-with-android-context-in-injected-bean)

Comment: @nmnd  your link is dead

Comment: @JamesKleeh your link is dead

Comment: Its a deleted question, what do you want me to do about it?

Answer (score 1):

**@Parameter** - Should be applied only to constructor arguments and Bean factory methods. [micronaut latest doc](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/api/io/micronaut/context/annotation/Parameter.html)

For example, you have a class

```
@Prototype
public class SomeService {

    @Inject
    private SomeClient client;

    private final String valueA;
    private final String valueB;

    public ReadActivityService(@Parameter String valueA, @Parameter String valueB) {
        this.valueA = valueA;
        this.valueB = valueB;
    }
    
}
```

and you want to create a new instance of the given bean SomeService performing dependency injection

```
@Singleton
@Requires(notEnv = Environment.TEST)
public class Starter {

    @Inject
    private ApplicationContext context;


    @EventListener
    public void init(final ServerStartupEvent event) {
        var service = context.createBean(SomeService.class, valueA, valueB);
    }

}
```